# How to translate 師資培訓授竹典禮 into English?

Tags: translation

My question is how to translate

> 師資培訓**授竹**典禮

into English?

In particular, I do not know how to translate

> **授竹**

The context is [an infomercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Tdk_xu9uDg) from a Buddhist university.

Comment: unable to access youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://tw.tzuchi.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&catid=92%3Aeducation-project&id=6432%3A2011-06-22-07-54-55&Itemid=385&lang=zh
>
> 「師者，傳道、授業、解惑也。」實習老師的授竹，取「竹」閔南語諧音「德」之意，期許老師為人師表要「高風亮節」，傳授品德教育。

「竹」(bamboo) in Minnan language pronounced the same as 「德」(virtue)

Giving the graduated teachers- in- training a piece of bamboo symbolically giving them 'virtue' (a high moral standard) -- to reminder them to live a virtuous life and teach moral lessons to their own students.

> 師資培訓授竹典禮 = Teacher qualifications training 'bamboo award' ceremony